# C# socket client server messages swap

Tags: c#, wpf, sockets, client-server

I have setup a client server chat system. That will have to work on different computers. At the moment I am testing and so both client and server are on my localhost.
At the moment I focus on the client reception (with a 8192 byte buffer) for it is that the problem resides.
And the problem is that when issue a command with very short text (here 123):

Server SHORT_COMMAND 123% ---> Client SHORT_COMMAND 123%

but when I issue a very long command (24k) each single batch does not arrive in the correct order
E.g. imagine a very long text 111.....11112222....2222333....33334444....4444
LONG_COMMAND 111....3333% is therefore automatically cut into

LONG_COMMAND 111....1111
2222....2222
3333...3333
4444...4444%
and sent in that order

what is wrong is the reception and what might happen is to receive

LONG_COMMAND 111....1111
2222....2222
4444...4444%
3333...3333

or it might get mixed with other short commands like

LONG_COMMAND 111....1111
2222....2222
SHORT_COMMAND 123%
3333...3333
4444...4444%

Take into account that some messages can be sent very quickly one after the other.

Thank you for ANY help

Patrick

---

> Client code

I start the client  with the following routine. In my case I pass -1

```
public static bool StartClient(string strIpAddress, string strPort)
{
    // Connect to a remote device.
    try
    {
        if (strIpAddress.Trim() == "-1")
            strIpAddress = GetLocalIPAddress();

        IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(strIpAddress);
        int port = int.Parse(strPort);
        IPEndPoint remoteEP = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);
        socketClient = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp) { NoDelay = true };
        socketClient.BeginConnect(remoteEP, new AsyncCallback(ConnectClientCallback), socketClient);
        OnNotification_Client?.Invoke(eSocketOperation.CONNECT, "Client connected to " + strIpAddress + " port=" + strPort, eSocketOperationResultType.SUCCESS);
        ReceiveClient();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("StartClient exc:" + e.ToString());
        return false;
    }
}
```

then

```
private static void ConnectClientCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        socketClient = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        socketClient.EndConnect(ar);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

---

The following part is the reception with:

```
public static void ReceiveClient()
{
    try
    {
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = socketClient;
        socketClient.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback_Client), state);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString(), "ReceiveClient", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
    }
}
```

finally

```
private static void ReceiveCallback_Client(IAsyncResult ar)
{

    try
    {
        StateObject state = (StateObject)ar.AsyncState;
        Socket client = state.workSocket;
        if (!client.Connected)
            return;
        int bytesRead = client.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0)
        {
            string message = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer, 0, bytesRead);
            if (message == null)
                OnNotification_Client?.Invoke(eSocketOperationResultType.ERROR, "Received null message from server", eSocketOperationResultType.ERROR);
            else
            {

                strReceivedMessageClient += message;
                if (strReceivedMessageClient.EndsWith(StateObject.CONFIRMATION.ToString()))
                {
                    ...
```

---

---

> Server Code

The server is started with

```
public static void StartServer(string _strPort)
{
    Serializers.Logger.WriteLog("StartServer");
    StrPort = _strPort;

    // Data buffer for incoming data.
    byte[] bytes = new Byte[BufferSize];

    IPAddress ipAddress = IPAddress.Parse(GetLocalIPAddress());
    int port = int.Parse(_strPort);
    IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);

    if (listener == null)
        listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

    try
    {
        listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
        listener.Listen(100);
        OnNotification_Server?.Invoke("Waiting for a connection on " + ipAddress.ToString());
        listener.BeginAccept(new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallbackServer), listener);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Accept

```
public static void AcceptCallbackServer(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    if (listener == null)
        return;

    listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);
    StateObject state = new StateObject();
    state.workSocket = handler;
    handler.BeginReceive(state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0, new AsyncCallback(ReceiveCallback_Server), state);
}
```

and last but not least the send:

```
public static void SendFromServerToClient(object command, String data, eSocketOperationResultType sort)
{
    string strMessage; ;
    strMessage = command.ToString() + '|' + data + '|' + sort + "%";

    byte[] byteData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(strMessage);
    try
    {
        if (socketServer != null)
            socketServer.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socketServer);
    }
    catch (Exception exc)
    {

    }
}

private static void SendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        Socket handler = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
        int bytesSent = handler.EndSend(ar);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(e.ToString());
    }
}
```

Comment: First of all, you connect asynchronously, but start Receiving without waiting for the connect to finish. I'd expect this to crash randomly, as soon as client and server reside on different machines. Even on the same machine, this is more than brittle. TCP keeps order, so the issue of losing order must be in your code. My bet is on the async code. I'd try switching to async/await or start with sync code on a seperate thread until things work, then move forward to async code.

Comment: TCP is a reliable communication protocol which means it is guaranteed that the remote end receives the messages in the order sent by the client. The code above lacks the client code, we cannot see how the messages are sent to the server. Is it a multi-threaded app? Also there is the strReceivedMessageClient  used in a static method the concat the received messages. Is this variable static, is it connection based or not? And as @fildor mentioned, you should start receiving in the ConnectClientCallback method after calling EndConnect()

Comment: @Fildor thanks for the your hint. Could you please propose a code? I can't find a suitable substitute per the AsyncCallback

Comment: @OguzOzgul thanks also to you for confirming that the tcp connection is reliable. Then, the code above is for the client, the server socketServer.BeginSend(byteData, 0, byteData.Length, 0, new AsyncCallback(SendCallback), socketServer);

Comment: Additionally sorry I can' t understand what you ask about the connection based

Comment: @Patrick Sorry, this is the client of course. Then we need the server code. Who is generating these LONG and SHORT Commands? How they are sent back to the client? If you send two consecutive commands like socket.Send(_24KCommand); socket.Send(_ShortCommand), there is no way that they got mixed up on the client side because the Send command on Socket is blocking. Are you sending them using BeginSend? We need the server code.

Comment: What I mean by "connection based" is; all the clients you setup by calling `public static bool StartClient(string strIpAddress, string strPort)` will WRITE the received commands to the same (possibly) static variable: strReceivedMessageClient and that can be the reason why your commands (actually sent to different clients) are intertwined.

Comment: There only is one client and one server so perhaps I might not make everything static. Do you think that this is causing the problem? I don't think so. I am posting the server code also thanks

Comment: If there is only one client then yes, a static variable should not be the problem. Can you please add the server code? How and when the commands are generated? In a multi-threaded way? On an interrupt from a device etc.?

Comment: Commands are generated in a multi-threaded ambient but in a sequential way for they are part of a state machine. In short the do a linear sequence of tasks. The problem is that some of those fire short messages and some very fast ones. Most are short one is long. That is causing the problem.

Comment: By running the server code (needed to implement some of the missing parts myself), and by preparing and sending short (20 Bytes) and long (24 KB) messages using 10 threads (9 for sending short messages and 1 for long ones), I was not able to reproduce the problem. The messages were received by the client in the correct order, without any problems. I really want to help.. Can you provide the full solution (full source code for client and server) somewhere?

Comment: I'd really need your help. Don't know where I could post, could you please kindly write me to patrick70 at inwind.it? Thanks a million!!